# Java quick file server (static files over HTTP)

Tags: java, http, fileserver

Is there Java ready-to-use tool, that would help me expose folder content as file server over HTTP.

Example, if I have

```
D:\Folder\file.zip
D:\Folder\file2.html
D:\Folder\folder\file-in-folder.jpg
```

Then starting in `D:\Folder\` `java java-file-server.jar`
I could access file via

```
http://hostname/file.zip
http://hostname/file2.html
http://hostname/folder/file-in-folder.jpg
```

There are of course Tomcat & Jetty but they need to be preinstalled, while I assume that only Java VM is present.
In Python & Node.js there are some commands to launch server, while the only close thing I know in Java is `mvn tomcat8:run` (or `mvn jetyy:run`), but that needs Maven, pom.xml and existing Java project.

The main requirement is that such server is installed and started via script.

Comment: Well you can embed jetty in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Alas no.  One can write one in Java, or as you have already noted download tools.  However unlike Python there is not a simple one liner supplied for us by the core JDK library.